# Fast api getting error value is not a valid list for get request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-2.7, fastapi

I am getting this error for get request  `value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)'`  but when remove my response model not getting any error. Here is my code and why getting this error for using response model and how to overcome this error

```
@router.get('/ads', response_model=List[schemas.ShowBlog])
def all_publish_blog(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    blogs = db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.is_published==True).all()
    if blogs:
        return { 
             
             "blogs":blogs
        }
    else:
         raise HTTPException(400, detail=f'din\'t find any published ads')
```

here is myschemas

```
class ShowBlog(BaseModel):
      title: str 
      body: str
      slug: str
      image_url: str
      ads_published_date: datetime
      ads_last_update_date:  Optional[datetime] = ...
      ads_comment: Optional[str] = ...
      users_bp: ShowUser
      class Config():
          orm_mode = True
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your GET http request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the piece of your code that reads

```
return { 
         
         "blogs":blogs
    }
```

returns a dictionary with the single key "blogs", presumably with the value being a list of blogs. The only way this schema would be validated by pydantic/fastapi is if your schema was written as such

```
class Blogs(BaseModel):
blogs: List[ShowBlog]
```

The response schema is currently expecting a list of blogs to be returned.

A potential fix for your issue as it stands is to just change your return statement to say
`return blogs`